# Primevue Grid and Flex layouts not rendering correctly

Tags: vue.js, flexbox, css-grid, primevue

Non WebDev here trying to build a basic UI with primevue on vue3. Tried to run the basic demo but with some components included. Don't know if components come with their own CSS dependencies.

Bellow is my html code. I have also tried using a vue project with separate components and gottenthe same result

Basic example fails:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>PrimeVue Demo</title>
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/primevue/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/primevue/resources/primevue.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/primeicons/primeicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue/inputtext/inputtext.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <p-inputtext v-model="val"></p-inputtext>
            <h6>{{val}}</h6>
        </div>


<div class="p-d-flex">
    <div class="p-mr-2">Item 1</div>
    <div class="p-mr-2">Item 2</div>
    <div>Item 3</div>
</div>

<div class="p-grid">
    <div class="p-col-4">4</div>
    <div class="p-col">1</div>
    <div class="p-col">1</div>
    <div class="p-col">1</div>
    <div class="p-col">1</div>
    <div class="p-col">1</div>
    <div class="p-col">1</div>
    <div class="p-col">1</div>
    <div class="p-col">1</div>
</div>

<div class="p-grid">
    <div class="p-col-2">2</div>
    <div class="p-col-6">6</div>
    <div class="p-col-4">4</div>
</div>

        <script>
            const {createApp, ref} = Vue;

            const App = {
                setup() {
                    const val = ref(null);

                    return {
                        val
                    };
                },
                components: {
                    'p-inputtext': primevue.inputtext
                } 
            };

            createApp(App).mount("#app");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Should render 1 row for flex items and 2 rows for numbers in grid layout. instead it renders all rows with no styling. What am I missing?:

[image: incorrectvuerendering]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use prime vue's flex and grid layout, you need to load PrimeFlex.

https://primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/primeflex

The documentation only has `npm` setup but you may be able to include the following link.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/primeflex@2.0.0/primeflex.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: That works. Thanks!  Now I just need to figure a way to enable the theme.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Installed primeflex with npm, and added stylesheet link.

Body text still has no styling. Is there a top level css tag I need to add or something?

Answer (score 3):

In case you do it through `npm`, After installing the package, don't forget to include the CSS file, in my case, I included it in my main.js just adding this line.

```js
import 'primeflex/primeflex.css';
```

https://primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/primeflex

Answer (score 1):

The CDN method works!! However I downloaded the file and placed this

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/primevue/primeflex.min.css" />
```

inside the head section of my html file.

However it did not work as per the documentation. I had to remove the p- for it to work:

```
<div id="app" class="grid">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
</div>
```